# backbone.js - templates won't render on asp.net view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I'm trying to render my backbone view into a asp.NET view, but underscore has the same open tags from asp.NET view (<% %>). I used the `_.templateSettings`, but the view still shows the `<@ @>` tags that I've changed for `/\<\@\=(.+?)\@\>/g`.

How can I load this backbone view differently?

Comment: How are you using the template with underscore? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Also, don't say you've used something, show exactly what you're doing. Sometimes it's just a typo.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, I've found a solution. I don't know if it's ok, but it works. But here's my view before this solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ANsyg1rPHOnEiHn4G8g5

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I would recommend using mustache/handlebars for your templates.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="someId">
<p> hello {{world}} </p>
</script>
```

and in your render function:

```
this.template = Mustache.to_html($("#someId").html(), this.model.toJSON())
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with lodash:

Add this js code after you load lodash.js:

```
if (typeof _ === 'function') {
    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        escape:      /\{%-(.+?)%\}/g,
        evaluate:    /\{%(.+?)%\}/g
    };
}
```

Now, you can make  use of `{%` and `%}` (instead of `<%` and `%>`):

some basic example:

```
<script id="hello" type="text/template">
    <span>My name is: {%=name%}</span>
</script>
```